# Why can't the Bernstein Bears work normally?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 7.0 and fixed in 9.0**

---

I want to use the *built-in* `BernsteinBasis[]` to learn about Bezier curves. I tried the following code:

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[D[BernsteinBasis[3, k, u], u], {k, 0, 3}], {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

I tried many workrounds. Finally, I added `PiecewiseExpand[]` before `BernsteinBasis[]`, then it works well.

```
Plot[Evaluate @ 
     Table[D[PiecewiseExpand @ BernsteinBasis[3, k, u], u], 
           {k, 0, 3}], {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

---

**Bug fixed**

[image]
[image]

Comment: `Evaluated->True` does the trick. You may search this site about it. `Plot[Table[D[BernsteinBasis[3, k, u], u], {k, 0, 3}], {u, 0, 1},  Evaluated -> True]`

Comment: @belisarius, In V8,`Plot[Table[D[BernsteinBasis[3, k, u], u], {k, 0, 3}], {u, 0, 1},  Evaluated -> True]` cannot give the result as OP shown.

Comment: This is version/system dependent. In v10.0.1 on a Mac, original input works fine without `Evaluated -> True` or `PiecewiseExpand`.

Comment: Original input works fine in V10.0.1 on Windows.

Comment: @RunnyKine, However, my *Mathematica* version is 8.0.4

Comment: I have no answer to this, but I wanted to comment that out of the corner of my eye I thought the question was "Why can't the Berenstain Bears work normally", which you must admit is pretty intriguing.

Comment: I'm sorry, you've misspelt *Berenstain*.

Comment: @Rahul Sorry, I think `Berenstain` is same with`Bernstein`.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in V8.0.4 is that

```
D[BernsteinBasis[3, 0, u], u]
```

evaluates as

```
3 (BernsteinBasis[2, -1, u] - BernsteinBasis[2, 0, u])
```

A negative second argument is disallowed.  The problem (i.e., bug) is that the general rule

```
D[BernsteinBasis[3, k, u], u]
(* 3 (BernsteinBasis[2, -1 + k, u] - BernsteinBasis[2, k, u]) *)
```

is applied when it is incorrect (e.g., for `k == 0` and `k == 3`).

This is fixed in V9 and V10.

It is interesting, if inexplicable, that it is accounted for when applying `PiecewiseExpand` to the result of the differentiation in V8.0.4:

```
PiecewiseExpand@D[BernsteinBasis[3, k, u], u]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]